# Where may I find a list of words used to describe relations and relationships?

Tags: nlp

I'm in a nlp project and there are millions of sentences which contains two entity. I want to find whether two entities have relationships or not in each sentence.

So I want to find a word list like:

```
['related to','induced by','the treatment of','The effects of','the treatment of','treated with','best for','in response to','approved for','response with','associated with','efficacy of ','in treating','applied to','efficacy in','efficacy and safety','efficacy at','impact on','approved','causing','but none of ','linked to','cause of','associated with','leading to','caused by','the relationship between','responsible for']
```

I have search github but I can't find it.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you edit your question and elaborate on what specifically you are trying to achieve? More info will help people answer your question. Specifically, can you give an example or two of a sentence, and clarify what you mean by "two entities having relationships" or not. Who are the entities? What do you mean by relationship? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see there are a vast number of ways in which a possible *semantic* relationship between two entities can be lexicalised (i.e. expressed by a word/expression) in language. Furthermore, this will be very dependent on the domain (e.g. politics, healthcare, engineering, astronomy, social sciences, etc, etc, etc). I'm not aware of any "ontology of relations".
By contrast, there will be less variety in the *syntactic* structures at play (i.e. [dependency relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar) or [constituent structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_structure_grammar), depending on the syntactic formalism you use). You should be able to identify (many of) these more easily than the actual list of words used (although having a list of word would be very useful). For example, for a given verb, if one entity (noun or noun phrase) is the subject and another entity (noun or noun phrase) the direct object, then that verb is likely to express a relation between the two. The same goes for indirect object, oblique object etc.
You can use a library like [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) to retrieve the grammatical (dependency) relations between verbs and nominal entities which you can then use to identify semantic relations. For example:

1. The Moon orbits the Earth.

   spaCy dependencies: `nsubj(orbits, Moon) obj(orbits, Earth)`

   semantic relation: `orbit(Moon, Earth)`
2. Trump was impeached by Congress.

   spaCy dependencies: `nsubjpass(impeach, Trump) agent(impeached, by) pobj(by, Congress)`

   semantic relation: `impeach(Congress, Trump)`

`spaCy` also takes care of [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) for you, although it is trained on a specific corpus that may not match your domain. Note that I have used the [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(morphology)) of the word to represent the relation (not the inflected verb form).

These are just simple examples and the number of configurations will be large and more complex verbal predicates exist (e.g. phrasal verbs), but you can pick up many semantic relations with a few patterns of grammatical dependencies just looking at simple verbs.

This requires a bit of work and I have not provided an implementation, but maybe this will help you make a start...?